# find index of element corresponding to another list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings: `ls = ['a','b','c']` and another one, with larger strings, guaranteed to include one and only one strings from `ls`: `ls2 = ['1298a', 'eebbbd', 'qcqcq321']"`.

How can I find, for a given string from `ls2`, what is the index of the corresponding string from `ls`?

I can use:

```
for s in ls:
    for ss in ls2:
        if s in ss:
            print (s,ss,ls.index(s))

a 1298a 0
b eebbbd 1
c qcqcq321 2
```

but it there something nicer?

**EDIT (hope it clarifies):**

The actual case I'm working on has a bigger 1st list, and a smaller 2nd:

```
ls  = ['apo','b','c','d25','egg','f','g']
ls2 = ['apoip21', 'oiujohuid25']
```

and I want to get the result `0,3` because the 1st item in `ls2` has the 1st item from `ls`, while the 2nd in `ls2` has the 4th in `ls`

Comment: @DunPeal. Every question is an algorithm question. There may be language features that simplify the algorithm though.

Comment: You could probably play with map and try to get this into a clever 1 liner.  But for me, even though it has 2 for loops, this is pretty readable and that is more important to me.  Unless you are having performance problems.

Comment: Are `ls` and `ls2` the same size with a 1-to-1 mapping, or is `ls2` bigger in the general case?

Comment: `ls` is always bigger, about 7 to 2 size difference

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to reflect that?

Comment: Also, are the elements of `ls` always one character long? If not, could you add that to your example as well?

Comment: Hum, might have been nice to define `nicer` clearer: shorter? Or less complex?

Comment: right right... looking for something less complex, i.e. one-liner, but not a list-comprehension... more like a function already implemented by pands/itertools and such

Comment: Here's another odd question. Is there ever a pair of elements in `ls` such that `sort(e1) == sort(e2)`. If not, you can really drop the complexity here.

Comment: No, all values are unique, in both lists (you can create a set from both lists stitched together without losing an element)

Comment: @CIsForCookies. That makes things more interesting.

Comment: @CIsForCookies. Although I just realized that that doesn't answer my question. What I'm asking is if you can have `ls = ['acb', 'cba']`, where `sort(ls[0]) == sort(ls[1])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can get away from `O(m * n * p)` complexity (where `m = len(ls)`, `n = len(ls2)`, `p = max(map(len, ls2))`) without further information about your data. You can definitely reduce your current loop from `O(m2 * n * p)` by keeping track of the current index using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Also, don't forget about early termination:

```
for string in ls2:
    for index, key in enumerate(ls):
        if key in string:
            print(key, string, index)
            break
```

Notice that I swapped the inner and outer loop to make the `break` work properly: you definitely want to check each element of `ls2`, but only the minimum number of elements in `ls`.

Here are some timings I accumulated on the different `O(m * n * p)` solutions presented here. Thanks to @thierry-lathuille for the test data:

```
ls = ['g', 'j', 'z', 'a', 'rr', 'ttt', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
ls2 = ['1298a', 'eebbb', 'qcqcq321', 'mlkjmd', 'dùmlk', 'lof',
       'erreee', 'bmw', 'ottt', 'jllll', 'lla' ]

def with_table():
    table = {key: index for index, key in enumerate(ls)}
    result = {}
    for string in ls2:
        for key in ls:
            if key in string:
                result[string] = table[key]
    return result

def with_enumerate():
    result = {}
    for string in ls2:
        for index, key in enumerate(ls):
            if key in string:
                result[string] = index
                break
    return result

def with_dict_comp():
    return {string: index for string in ls2 for index, key in enumerate(ls) if key in string}

def with_itertools():
    result = {}
    for (index, key), string in itertools.product(enumerate(ls), ls2):
        if key in string:
            result[string] = index
    return result
```

```
%timeit with_table()
4.89 µs ± 61.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit with_enumerate()
5.27 µs ± 66.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit with_dict_comp()
6.9 µs ± 83.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit with_itertools()
17.5 ns ± 0.193 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

As it turns out, creating a lookup table for the indices is slightly faster than computing them on the fly with `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict comprehension:

```
ls  = ['apo','b','c','d25','egg','f','g']
ls2 = ['apoip21', 'oiujohuid25']

result = { string : index for index, i in enumerate(ls) for string in ls2 if i in string }
# {'apoip21': 0, 'oiujohuid25': 3}
```

Comment: You've violated OP's first assumption: only one element of `ls` per element of `ls2`.

Comment: Your result is backwards. The keys should be elements in `ls2`

Comment: Same complexity, but much better now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, it actually answers the question now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your codes time complexity is O(n^4), you can make it O(n^3) by using dict.

```
ls = ['a','b','c']
ls2 = ['1298a', 'eebbbd', 'qcqcq321']
word_dict=dict()
for i in range(len(ls)):    #time complexity O(n)

    word_dict[ls[i]]=i
for s in ls:    #O(n)
    for ss in ls2:  #O(n)
        if s in ss: #O(n)
            print(s,ss,word_dict[s]) #O(1)
```

Comment: This is no improvement on what OP is doing. You could just enumerate your list to get the same info with one fewer loop.

Comment: time complexity reduced here.

Comment: No it's not. OP has O(n^2) solution as well. Yours just adds an extra layer of overhead.

Comment: "in" operator takes O(n), finding index in the last line takes O(n),two loops take O(n^2). So it's O(n^4).

Comment: Actually it's `O(m * n * p)`, where `m = len(ls)`, `n = len(ls2)`, and `p = max(len(x) for x in ls2)`

Comment: What about the complexity of `index()` function?is it O(1)?

Comment: I would expect index to have the exact same complexity as `in`: a linear search is a linear search. The only difference is the return value.

Comment: `in` operator takes O(n), `index()` takes O(n). So here at least time complexity is O(m * n * p * q) ~ O(n^4)

Comment: When you say index, you mean `word_dict[s]`? I thought you were mulling over the idea of using `str.index` somehow. `word_dict[s]` is O(1). `dict` is a hash table.

Comment: `for s in ls`: #O(n)
    `for ss in ls2`:  #O(m)
        `if s in ss`: #O(p)
            `print (s,ss,ls.index(s))` #(q) because of `ls.index()` function. so overall O(m * n* p * q)

Comment: Sorry, I'm slow today. You were referring to OP's original version. You could get around it much easier by just enumerating on the inner loop.

Comment: yeah, that's a different option too

Comment: I did some timings, and you're right. enumerate may look shorter, but a lookup table is actually faster.

Comment: Yeah,here enumerate is shorter but with high time complexity

Comment: Not really higher complexity. Just greater load factor.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I interpret the "nicer" request as "written in a more compact way", then I suggest all loops and conditions packed in a list comprehension:

```
>>> ls  = ['apo','b','c','d25','egg','f','g']
>>> ls2 = ['apoip21', 'oiujohuid25']

>>> [ls.index(s) for s in ls for s2 in ls2 if s in s2]
[0, 3]
```

But it does not improve the complexity, if "nicer" was to be understood as "less complex"...

Answer (score 0):

You could use these two improvements:

```
ls = ['a','b','c']
ls2 = ['1298a', 'eebbbd', 'qcqcq321']

# preprocess ls to avoid calling ls.index each time:
indices = {ss:index for index, ss in enumerate(ls)}

for s in ls2:
    for ss in ls:
        if ss in s:
            print(ss, s, indices[ss])
            # as s is guaranteed to include only one of the substrings,
            # we don't have to test the other substrings once we found a match
            break


# a 1298a 0
# b eebbbd 1
# c qcqcq321 2
```

---

Some timings:

Breaking out of the loop once the match has been found always improves the speed.
The overhead due to the creation of the dict of indices makes it slower for very small lists, but is already faster with lists shorter than the ones used in the timings:

```
ls = ['g', 'j', 'z', 'a', 'rr', 'ttt', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
ls2 = ['1298a', 'eebbb', 'qcqcq321', 'mlkjmd', 'dùmlk', 'lof', 'erreee', 'bmw', 'ottt', 'jllll', 'lla' ]

def original():
    for s in ls:
        for ss in ls2:
            if s in ss:
                out = (s,ss,ls.index(s))


def with_break():

    for s in ls2:
        for ss in ls:
            if ss in s:
                out = (ss, s, ls.index(ss))
                # as s is guaranteed to include only one of the substrings,
                # we don't have to test the other substrings once we found a match
                break


def with_break_and_dict():
    # preprocess ls to avoid calling ls.index each time:
    indices = {ss:index for index, ss in enumerate(ls)}

    for s in ls2:
        for ss in ls:
            if ss in s:
                out = (ss, s, indices[ss])
                # as s is guaranteed to include only one of the substrings,
                # we don't have to test the other substrings once we found a match
                break
```

Timing results:

```
%timeit original()
%timeit with_break()
%timeit with_break_and_dict()


# 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.8 µs per loop
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.5 µs per loop
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.49 µs per loop
```

Comment: As discussed under [@TaohidulIslam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743104/2988730), you are suggesting adding more overhead, not adding an improvement. Also you answer is almost identical.

Comment: @MadPhysicist See the timings

Comment: The first one is not a fair comparison. See the answer I posted. See if `enumerate` makes it faster than a lookup table. I bet it does.

Comment: Also, would be interesting to see the `itertools.product` version.

Comment: I added more timings to my answer. Looks like you're right. The lookup table is better than my original solution.